# How would I add a shortcut to a folder within another folder SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, shortcut

We've got a folder structure as below,

Approved Invoices

John Doe

- Approved
- In Query

Jane Doe

- Approved
- In Query

What we'd like is for there to be a shortcut to the top level folder in each users folder so they can add files in there for our finance team to process.

Approved Invoices

John Doe

- Approved Invoices
- In Query

Jane Doe

- Approved Invoices
- In Query

This is a piece of cake with Windows Explorer, Just create a shortcut and copy it to each users folder, however in SharePoint shortcuts don't work the same. I've tried creating a URL file but it doesn't allow us to drag and drop so it doesn't work for our use case since all of our users sync the library with their local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Map your library as a network drive, which will allow you to access SharePoint through Windows File Explorer.
Notice:
1, you need at least access/read permissions to the library to map the drive
2. This process will not work in Chrome or Firefox.
Specific steps are as follows:

1. Using Internet Explorer or Edge, browse to the SharePoint library you want to map to as a drive.
2. In the Ribbon(please change to Classic Experience), click the Library tab > Open with Explorer.
3. Mouse over the folder path at the top of the Explorer window. Click to the right of the library name. The path turns into a web address and highlights. Right click and copy the URL.
4. In the Ribbon in File Explorer, click the Home tab > Easy access > Map as drive.
5. In the Map Network Drive pop-up, choose an available drive letter (your preference), paste the URL you copied in step 3, and leave the other options as shown below.
6. Click Finish. The SharePoint library is now available as a drive in File Explorer.

For more information, you can refer to [this article](https://medium.com/jumpto365/get-to-sharepoint-through-windows-file-explorer-4630c9d5b43e).

Comment: Hi , I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? 

If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut file with a target like `C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:Profile\sharepoint_site\synced_root_folder\path\to\folder`

Answer (score 0):

In the SharePoint folder, Use the "Add shortcut to OneDrive " option at the top to provide a folder link in their OneDrive. They can then add files from their local device.

If necessary you could create separate folders for each member of staff in SharePoint for them to individually connect.